# Creating dynamic PDF internal links with BIRT

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, birt

I am trying to create a PDF in BIRT and I need to have bookmarks linking from a summary page to each detail page. The links work fine in the HTML preview and a similar http link works in published PDFs. However, the internal links do not work in the PDF format.

What I have tried so far is setting the *bookmark* property to `"detail_" + row["nodeid"]` and setting the hyperlink to the same. As stated, this works for the HTML preview, but not the PDF export.

The PDF has automatically generated TOC items that I would prefer to leverage off, but I don't know how to link to those.

Is there a way that I can get the PDF output to contain the required links using either bookmark properties, or the generated TOC items?

[Sample PDF output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lpfCZJkwykBguelzZTsS48gCCecO48jE/view?usp=sharing) (Customer data removed, alternate locations selected)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem lies not in the format of the bookmark/hyperlink, but in the placement of the bookmark.

The problem was, I was placing the bookmark on the row of the table I wanted to link to. Instead, the bookmark needed to be on the label in the first column of the row.

I believe the issue is that, in the HTML version, the table row is a `<tr>` tag, however in the PDF, the row doesn't physically exist, so there's nothing to set the bookmark on. However the label/text item exists in both versions, so the bookmark is created correctly.